# rails nested form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get a nested form to display with empty fields (currently existing data is being shown).  SOLVED THIS PART, SEE UPDATE.

Also I'm trying to find a way to edit each nested form entry one at a time, currently i can only get the edit to display all nested form entries on the same form when editing.  ideally I would like a link next to each job title with the ability to edit just that one entry instead of all entries opening in edit mode.

users controller

```
# renders the users/new.html.erb form
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.work_histories.build # used for nested attributes in forms
end


# renders the users/edit.html.erb view form
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.work_histories.build # used for nested forms
end

# white listed form attributes for user and also for nested attributes (work history, qualifications, etc...). 
 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :current_job_title, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                  work_histories_attributes: [:user_id, :id, :job_title, :company, :description, :city, :state,:start_date, :end_date])
 end
```

User Model

```
      # allows for nested attributes in the user views.
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_histories, allow_destroy: true, 
  reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['job_title'].blank?}
```

WorkHistory Model

```
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

The show view for User.  the modal displays the user field for first_name but not the work histories fields.

```
<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="experienceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="experienceModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Experience</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

      <!-- one-to-many nested attributes -->  
      <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

            <%= f.label :first_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, size: 40, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.fields_for :work_histories do |ff| %>

            <%= ff.label :job_title %>
            <%= ff.text_field :job_title, size: 40, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>

        <% end %><!-- fields_for -->

        <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

      </div><!-- modal body -->

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      <% end %><!-- form_for -->  

    </div><!-- modal-content -->
  </div><!-- modal dialog -->
</div><!-- modal -->
```

**UPDATE:**
OK I figured out how to get the form to display empty so i can have users fill in data instead of the form being displayed with existing user data.  just had to add WorkHistory.new in the view.

```
 <%= form_for @user do |user_form| %>

  <%= user_form.label :first_name %>
  <%= user_form.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= user_form.fields_for :work_histories, WorkHistory.new do |wh_fields| %>
      job: <%= wh_fields.text_field :job_title %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating this in case someone stumbles upon it in the future.  For getting a blank nested form to display so users can input data see the section called UPDATE in my original question.

To actually edit an existing nested form record see below, had to pass both the user id as well as the work history id.

```
    <table>
  <!-- one-to-many association to loop through a users qualifications -->
  <% @user.work_histories.each do |w| %>        
<tr>
  <td>        
    <h4><b><%= link_to w.job_title, edit_user_work_history_path(user_id: @user.id, id: w.id) %></b></h4>
    <!--<h4><b><%= link_to w.job_title, edit_user_work_history_path(user_id: @user.id, id: w.id), data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#experienceModal"} %></b></h4>-->
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= w.company %>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= w.start_date.strftime("%b %Y") %> - <%= w.end_date.strftime("%b %Y") %>
  </td>
</tr>  
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= w.city %>, <%= w.state %>
  </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td>
    <br />
    <%= w.description %>
  </td>
</tr>  
<tr>
  <td>
    <br />
    <hr>
  </td>
</tr>      
 <% end %>
```